# Calling a method inside webservice to create record

Tags: webservices

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v/restAPIKeyGeneration/*')
global with sharing class APIforKeyGeneration{
    @HttpPost
    global static String createAccount(){
    SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey();
    return 'record crea';
    }
}

public class SourceMDMRestAPI{
public static string GenerateKey(){
string keyGenerationString='';
    string keyGenerationString1='';
       Account m=new Account(Name='sarada',BillingCity='rere',BillingPostalCode='12',Phone='8008809995');
        system.debug('m.Candidate_Key__c'+m.Candidate_Key__c);
        if(m.Phone != ''){
      system.debug('if calles'+ m.Candidate_Key__c);
      m.Candidate_Key__c=m.Phone;
       system.debug('if calles'+ m.Candidate_Key__c);
      string s=m.Candidate_Key__c;
     } 
      if(m.Name != '' && m.BillingCity!= ''){
      system.debug('if calles'+ m.Candidate_Key3__c);
      keyGenerationString += KeyFormationTriggerController.toSoundex(String.valueof(m.Name));
      keyGenerationString1 += KeyFormationTriggerController.Metaphone(String.valueof(m.BillingCity));
      m.Candidate_Key3__c=keyGenerationString+keyGenerationString1;
      string r=m.Candidate_Key3__c;
            system.debug('if calles'+ m.Candidate_Key3__c);

      }


    return m.Candidate_Key__c+':'+m.Candidate_Key3__c;
}
}
```

Urgent requirement, please help how can i do it ? can i create a record from this SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey(); without using insert m; statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its just a normal method call that returns a value so:

```
@HttpPost
global static String createAccount(){
    String key = SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey();
    // Use key in here...
    return 'record crea';
}
```

Comment: my question is ,,can i create a record from this SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey(); without using insert m; statement

Comment: @sahisfdc To create a record in the database you have to use an insert. Why don't you want to do an insert?

Comment: if i use insert ,trigger will be fired ryt,,i dnt want to fire the trigger,using webservices post method,to create

Comment: @sahisfdc If by "create" you mean insert in the database then you are stuck. Unless it is your trigger: if it is your trigger you can set a static field while you do the insert and check that in the trigger.

Comment: forget about the trigger,is there any way,can create create without using insert that means,using webservice as shown in above code,,please let me know,thanks in advance

Comment: @sahisfdc You can create an object in memory and manipulate it there. But if you want it to persist you need to insert it into the database.